# ClamAV found virus, if I should delete this virus?

Tags: linux, security

ClamAV has found two viruses on my server. 
Is this a virus? Should I delete it?

```
/tmp/back: Perl.Shellbot-8 FOUND

/var/tmp/back: Perl.Shellbot-8 FOUND
```

Answer (score 1):

Block all traffic going out to port 23 of a remote server using your firewall:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 23 -j DROP
```

According to Symantec, the destination is host 72.167.37.182 therefore if you want to be more specific (or need outgoing port 23 to other hosts - hopefully not as it's telnet):

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 72.167.37.182 --dport 23 -j DROP
```

Then take time to try and find out if it has actually infected your machine - ClamAV may have caught it in time.

You could possibly log the dropped packets by replicating the above rules with `DROP` replaced by `LOG`.  For example:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 72.167.37.182 --dport 23 -j LOG
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 72.167.37.182 --dport 23 -j DROP
```

If you see results in your log then you've been infected...

But as @Jan says - you may have been infected by now and you can't know for certain what damage has been done.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you **can** delete it. Your question probably means *Should I delete it?*  and as such, is too broad.

If I were you, I'd nuke the system and re-install from scratch, but then again, that depends on the environment and usecase.

Comment: I can not reinstall, I bought a server and on it I have 120 sites. You think that will not solve the problem by deleting the virus on the server?

Comment: It can not be known if that solves the issue. Your machine probably has other - undetected - notorious stuff as well by now. Personally, I would never trust a machine that had a virus. You can of course revert to an earlier (LVM|FS) snapshot or backup. You **do** have backups, I hope?

Comment: Backup accounts I work through cPanel. Every day for the last 30 days. I have problems only thing we arrived a large number of spam mails about 3000 a day and during the day is about 30 access attempts in the cPanel (user and root) which were rejected.